# Embed Tomcat 7 in Android Application

Tags: android, tomcat, embed

I need to embed Tomcat 7 in android application so that it can run local web application as a standalone application. I am able to embed Tomcat in Java Application. Now, I want to achieve the same for an Android application. Please suggest me where to start. I-jetty and NanoHttpd are already available for this purpose, but I need to use specifically Tomcat that too embedded in the android application. For Java application, I am using the following code from Apache Tomcat 7. I want to know how to use this same Embedded Tomcat API in Android. If I use this this API in android in my Activity's OnCreate() method

```
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer;
import org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
public class EmbeddedTomcat {
    private Tomcat tomcat;
    private void startTomcat() throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
        this.tomcat = new Tomcat();
        this.tomcat.setPort(8080); #2
        this.tomcat.setBaseDir("."); #3
        // Add AprLifecycleListener 
        StandardServer server = (StandardServer) this.tomcat.getServer();
        AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
        server.addLifecycleListener(listener); #4
        String contextPath = "/myapp";
        String appBase = "/opt/tomcat7/webapps/examples";
        this.tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, appBase); #5
        this.tomcat.start(); #6
    }
    private void stopTomcat() throws LifecycleException {
        this.tomcat.stop(); #7
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            EmbeddedTomcat tomcat = new EmbeddedTomcat(); #8
            tomcat.startTomcat();
            Thread.sleep(100000);
            tomcat.stopTomcat();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to use this same Embedded Tomcat API in Android. If I use this this API in android in my Activity's onCreate() method as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Tomcat tomcat;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            startTomcat();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void startTomcat() throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
    this.tomcat = new Tomcat();
    this.tomcat.setPort(8080);
    this.tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
    // Add AprLifecycleListener 
    StandardServer server = (StandardServer) this.tomcat.getServer();
    AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
    server.addLifecycleListener(listener);
    String contextPath = "/myapp";
    String appBase = "/opt/tomcat7/webapps/examples";
    this.tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, appBase);
    this.tomcat.start();
    }
    private void stopTomcat() throws LifecycleException {
    this.tomcat.stop();
    }
}
```

When I run this, it give error "Conversion to Dalvik failed with error 1".
If what I am trying to do is not possible, please suggest any other way to embed Tomcat in Android application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever got that running?